# R: Iterate/accumulate a parameter within lapply

Tags: r

`lapply(rep(list(sample(1:100)), 10), sort, partial = 1:10)`

... is what I'm trying to do. But the **partial = 1:10** term is only evaluated once. What is the simplest method to evaluate the list of ten sample(1:100)'s with ten **i++**-style values passed to partial?

I apologize for being inarticulate.

A follow-up question is whether there is a more efficient method of generating these samples. What might this look like in a single custom function?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do? Are you saying that you would like the "partial" argument to change each time?

Comment: `Map(function(l,p) sort(l, partial = p), rep(list(sample(1:100)), 10), 1:10)`?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question: you can use the multivariate version of `sapply`/`lapply`, eg

```
mapply(sort, x = list(sample(1:100, 10)), partial = 1:10)
```

If you want to return a `list`, set `SIMPLIFY` to `FALSE`.